# GCM push notification multithreading

Tags: multithreading, google-cloud-messaging, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

We have been developing an Android App which sends the updates to our App users.The updates are posted to our server from an Admin console(JAVA SWING Application) and then stored in database.Once the data is succesfully inserted into database , we wish to send the same update to every user of app through GCM push notification. As we want to build the system to cater millions of people we would like to use multithreading(may be using executor service) for pushing notifciation.GCM can be sent to 1000 devices(lets call it as bunch) at once.So we need to first make a list of bunch(each bunch contain 1000 gcmids).So the series of tasks would be
1.Insert data in db
2.Create the list of bunch
3.Then send the notification to each bunch

Step3 is where we plan to use multithreading.But I want to return after step1 itself so that client will be intimated the response(JAVA SWING APP should be definetley initimated  abt whether data is inserted into DB or not and it has no interest abt success of GCM push)

So how do I design such stuff to return from step 1 and next 2 should be done in main  thread and step3 
should be attained using multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with background processing or worker processes.

There are several ways to execute this kind of long running tasks in background so the requested client need not to wait.

Some of the tools that do this kind of things are Job/Worker Queues. Its possible with Gearman, Redis Resque, Iron MQ(there are many Message queues available which can be used as jobb queues).